# randomNumber not working

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>First javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <script src="randomNumber.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    getRandomNumber();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="hello">Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Javascript file.

```
window.onload = function getRandomNumber(){
  var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  console.log(randomNum);
  document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML += randomNum;
}
```

I cant understand why the code is not working. I am new to programming so if you could give a quick  then that would be great.

It's working.

Comment: Move your `<script>` tags to the very end of the `<body>`, after the `<p>`. That way, the DOM will have been built and will include that element so that your `.getElementById()` call will find it.

Comment: Does your `console.log` fire at all?